# Error NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, xna-4.0

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Bile.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Code:

```
Cerc ceva = GenerateNewParticle();
cercuri.Add(ceva);
```

The error is in second line, and i don't know why, because my function shouldn't return null

```
public Cerc GenerateNewParticle()
    {

        Vector2 position = Location;
        Random random = new Random();
        Color color = new Color(
                    (float)random.NextDouble(),
                    (float)random.NextDouble(),
                    (float)random.NextDouble());

        return new Cerc(Texture, position, color);
    }
```

This is from Cerc class

```
public class Cerc
{
    public Texture2D Texture;
    public Color Color;
    float x = 0, y = 0;
    float varx = 2, vary = 2;
    public Cerc(Texture2D texture,Vector2 location,Color color)
    {
        x = location.X + 50;
        y = location.Y + 50;
        Texture = texture;
        Color = color;
    }
```

Comment: `cercuri` is `null`. You haven't shown what it is or where it comes from.

Comment: This is cercuri:
    public List<Cerc> cercuri;

Comment: Did you initialize `cercuri` before adding an item into it ? Otherwise, you will have to do this: `cercuri = new List<Cerc>();`